# How to include the Match object into a Reacts component class?

Tags: reactjs, react-class-based-component

I am using react router v5, and trying to get URL parameters by props match object into my react component class. However it is not working! What am I doing wrong here?

When I create my component as a JavaScript function it all works fine, but when I try to create my component as a JavaScript class it doesn't work.

Perhaps I am doing something wrong? How do I pass the Match object in to my class component and then use that to set my component's state?

here code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';   

import { Link} from "react-router-dom";

export class JobDetail extends Component {  

    state = {
       // jobsData: [],

    }
    async componentDidMount() {

        const props = this.props.match;
        console.log("---props data---",props);  // it's showing undefined 

    }


    render() {  
        return (  
            <>
                test message 
            </> 

        )  
    }  
}  
  
export default JobDetail
```